# How to find a city(ies) only with partial search?

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

I am using Nominatim OpenStreetMap API to find city/ cities which matches search phrase.

For example, **wind** should work like `Wind%` - not an exact match but it does not work. The second problem is not able to get a city/cities. It returns, administrative, town, county, recreational and etc.

The Nominatim documentation suggests using special words but there is no example.

> https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?format=json&addressdetails=1&q=winds&format=json&limit=5

The above URL returns 5 places but not a single city. I want to search for cities only. I can use the following which is kind of helpful but it does not search for a partial phrase and returns a result only with exact matcth:

> https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?format=json&addressdetails=1&city=windsor&format=json&limit=5

If instead of `city=windsor` I use `city=wind` it does not return data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Nominatim doesn't support partial matches. But [photon](https://photon.komoot.de/) does.